# Media Resource Control Protocol (MRCP) and Dictation (Speech Recognition without Grammars)

Tags: protocols, speech-recognition, network-protocols, ivr, dictation

Does Media Resource Control Protocol (**MRCP**)  tells about **Speech Recognition** but does not tell anything about **Dictation** (Speech Recognition without sending Grammars).At least I can not find anything.

> Why it does not? Or do I understand MRCP wrong? If so what MRCP says about **Dictation**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MRCP does not tell anything about *Dictation* (free speech). If recognizer support *Dictation* then it should have corresponding grammar defined as build-in grammar. Then you can set grammar for *Dictation* and recognize free speech.